# mapping SKUs on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a set of SKUs(stockkeeping unit) for various items that I need to map to their indexes;
example:

```
| __SKU_ID__|   __Item_Name__   |   __Price__  |

|ST1200     |SwissCheese        |   $3.25      |
```

the ID is composed of 3 sets of unique identifiers containing 2 characters each, which would otherwise look like this: [ST],[12],[00]

but considering theres no **arrays** in mysql, I cant find away around it. is there an alternative to array or another way i can do this?

Comment: What do you mean "map to their indexes"?

Comment: Assuming there is some relevance to the individual components, then you need look no further than first normal form. If you must accomodate an incomptent schema then use a view to create a mapping or decompose the composite attribute.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part `[ST]` use `LEFT`: `SELECT LEFT(SKU_ID, 2) ...`

For the middle part `[12]` use `MID`: `SELECT MID(SKU_ID, 3, 2) ...` `3` defines the 3rd position in the string so starting with 1 and the `2` defines the length of the mid substring returning `12`

For the last part `[00]` use `RIGHT`: `SELECT RIGHT(SKU_ID, 2) ...`

Then you can go on to do as you need to.

`SELECT 
    LEFT(SKU_ID,2) AS left, 
    MID(SKU_ID,3,2) AS middle, 
    RIGHT(SKU_ID,2) AS right 
FROM Table ...`

Comment: sorry one more question, what if the SKU is longer than 6 characters, but is 12 cahracters long, would it be

SELECT LEFT(SKU_ID, 4, 2) .. ?

Comment: @CannedOnion go on?

Comment: @CannedOnion you need to adapt *your* code to fit *your* circumstances. Get Creative.

Comment: @CannedOnion Left and right always start at the left most/right most character so you only need to define a length so `LEFT (SKU_ID,length)` similarly for right. As for mid the 1st number defines starting position and second number defines length.